# Behat/Mink/Selenium2 unable to access elements on page

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I'm trying to work through Behat docs Wikipedia example. Goutte works as expected, but when I try using selenium 2 I get
`Field()
      Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "search" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)`

This is the feature that has issues
`Scenario: Searching for a page with autocompletion
  Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
  When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driv"
  And I wait for the suggestion box to appear
  Then I should see "Behavior Driven Development"`

my behat.yml

`default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            browser_name: firefox
            base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
            #goutte: ~
            selenium2:
              browser: firefox`

When I change the value to search for from "search" I get the same error.

update: composer.json

`{
    "name": "company/behat",
    "description": "test project for behat",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Anonymous",
            "email": "anon@anon.com.au"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.3",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.3",
        "behat/mink": "^1.7",
        "peridot-php/webdriver-manager": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}`

Comment: For using a browser add `@javascript` tag at feature level, after this see if you need to add any wait.

Comment: I've used the @javascript tag and added an 8 second wait but it still only returns null. Interestingly I can return the page objects html but it can't find anything within it.

Comment: @minkStruggler Did you figure this out? I am going through the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure you are on the "/wiki/Main_Page" page ?
(Silly question but you never know...)

I can only propose you some debug functions or tool to debug

- [**TightVNC**](https://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) a really usefull tool to see onlive your Scenario running. You just have to insert your selenium url (default password is 'secret').
- Some functions I have added on my FeatureContext:

``

```
/**
 * afterTheStep
 *
 * If the current step is failing, then print the html code of
 * the current page and, if the driver is an instance of
 * Selenium2Driver, print a screenshot of the current page.
 *
 * @AfterStep
 *
 * @param   AfterStepScope  $scope
 * @return  BaseFeatureContext
 */
public function afterTheStep(AfterStepScope $scope): ?self
{
    if (99 !== $scope->getTestResult()->getResultCode()) {
        return null;
    }

    $filePath  = __FILE__ . '../debug/behat/';
    // override if is set into behat.yml

    $fileName = date('d-m-y').'_'.basename($scope->getFeature()->getfile()).'_'.hash('md5', $scope->getStep()->getText());
    $this->takeScreenshot($filePath, $fileName);
    $this->takePageContent($filePath, $fileName);
    $this->getErrorPosition($filePath, $fileName, $scope);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * takeScreenshot
 *
 * save a screenshot of the current page if the driver is
 * an instance of Selenium2Driver
 *
 * @param   string  $filePath
 * @param   string  $fileName
 * @return  BaseFeatureContext
 */
private function takeScreenshot(string $filePath, string $fileName): self
{
    $driver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();

    if (!$driver instanceof Selenium2Driver) {
        return $this;
    }

    $filePath = $filePath.'screenshot/';
    $extension =  '.png';
    $fullPath  = $filePath.$fileName.$extension;

    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        mkdir($filePath, 0777, true);
    }
    if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
        unlink($fullPath);
    }

    $this->saveScreenshot($fileName.$extension, $filePath);
    echo(sprintf(
        "Result screenshot at: %s \n",
        $fullPath
    ));

    return $this;
}

/**
 * takePageContent
 *
 * save the html code of the current page
 *
 * @param   string  $fileName
 */
private function takePageContent(string $filePath, string $fileName): self
{
    $filePath  = $filePath.'report/';
    $extension =  '.txt';
    $fullPath  = $filePath.$fileName.$extension;


    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        mkdir($filePath, 0777, true);
    }
    if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
        unlink($fullPath);
    }

    file_put_contents($fullPath, $this->getSession()->getPage()->GetContent());
    echo(sprintf(
        "Result HTML page content at: %s \n",
        $fullPath
    ));

    return $this;
}

/**
 * getErrorPosition
 *
 * print the position of the error
 *
 * @param   string          $filepath
 * @param   string          $filename
 * @param   AfterStepScope  $scope
 */
private function getErrorPosition(string $filePath, string $fileName, AfterStepScope $scope): self
{
    // eval(\Psy\sh());
    $filePath  = $filePath.'position/';
    $extension =  '.txt';
    $fullPath  = $filePath.$fileName.$extension;
    $fileContent = sprintf(
        "Error in file \n'%s'\n
        Title: '%s'\n
        Description:\n'%s'\n
        Line %s : '%s'\n
        Exception:\n'%s'\n",
        $scope->getFeature()->getFile(),
        $scope->getFeature()->getTitle(),
        $scope->getFeature()->getDescription(),
        $scope->getStep()->getLine(),
        $scope->getStep()->getText(),
        $scope->getTestResult()->getException()->getMessage()
    );

    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        mkdir($filePath, 0777, true);
    }
    if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
        unlink($fullPath);
    }

    file_put_contents($fullPath, $fileContent);
    echo(sprintf(
        "Position of error at: %s \n",
        $fullPath
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

``